# Joomla! russian language file ( ini ) issue

Tags: joomla3.0, multilingual

I am creating a multilanguage web site in joomla!. English and Russian. When I tried to edit the "languages/ru-RU.ini" and added the following line

```
CALLUS="озвоните нам"
```

When save and reopen the "ini" file then the "озвоните нам" part will goes like

```
CALLUS="????????? ???"
```

In main site also giving those question marks.

Any idea guys ?
Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try open it with an editor like Notepad++ and make sure format->encode UTF-8 (No BOM) is selected, and if not then choose the Convert to UTF-8 (No BOM), and then save.

Should solve your problem.